# Category count inside the link

Tags: categories

Is it possible using `wp_list_categories` set count of post in category in the `href`?

Comment: It's possible, with some regular expression jiggery pokery. Some variation on [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Remove_Parentheses_from_Category_Counts)

Answer (score 5):

Regular expression jiggery pokery identified:

```
<?php
$categories = wp_list_categories('title_li=&show_count=1&echo=0');
$categories = preg_replace('/<\/a> \(([0-9]+)\)/', ' <span class="count">[\\1]</span></a>', $categories);
echo $categories;
?>
```

Comment: nice solution @vancoder, but `preg_replace` might be a better choice because  `ereg_replace` is deprecated since php 5.3, according to http://php.net/ereg_replace.

Comment: @birgire Excellent point, answer updated.