# show count is out of the anchor tag in wp_list_categories

Tags: css, categories

I'm using wp_list_categories with 'show_count' enabled on that, i styled my `<a>` tag, but the category count doesn't show up under anchor tag.(it's under `li`)

```
$args = array(
            'orderby'            => 'ASC',
            'show_count'         => 1,
            'pad_counts'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 0,
            'title_li'           => '',
            'taxonomy'           => 'genre'
```

I didn't find anything on [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) page.
[image]

Is there anyway to push the count number into the anchor tag? so it should be get the style.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/category-count-inside-the-link) with a quick fix or did you try writing your own custom walker?

Comment: Bit of a guess, but that looks a lot like dumped data not fully formatted output. Could there be debugging code left somewhere?